# I want the user to take 1 hour and 10 minutes to give a message that the amount of time remaining

Tags: c#, .net

I want the user to take 1 hour and 10 minutes to give a message that the amount of time remaining

this my code

```
        string your = txt2.Text;
        string format = "HH:mm:ss";
        DateTime your1 = DateTime.Parse(your);
        while (DateTime.Now < your1)
        {
            TimeSpan left = your1 - DateTime.Now;
            DateTime left1 = Convert.ToDateTime(left.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(left1.ToString() + "1");


        }
        MessageBox.Show("times up");
```

Comment: what is the your output(current/expected) ?

Comment: I don't think that throwing MesasgeBox in a loop is the right approach. The right thing would be to update some Label with time remaining from a Timer (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you create a form (instead of the MessageBox.Show). Inside this form you can display the remaining time and add a timer that calls "this.close()" after a period of time